# Item Templete for gridview in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, gridview, xamarin.forms, itemtemplate

I want to use a item template inside a gridview, so that all the childs looks the same, will that be possible? Or is there any work around for the same, in Xamarin Forms.

Here is my item template.

```
               <FlexLayout
                    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    Direction="Column" AlignContent="Center"
                    MinimumHeightRequest="110"
                    WidthRequest="90"
                    >
                    <Button BorderColor="#fff"
                        BorderWidth="1"
                        BackgroundColor="#4D000000"
                        HeightRequest="90" CornerRadius="45"
                        Image="vera"/>

                    <Label Text="Chat" 
                        Margin="0,4,0,0"
                        HeightRequest="20"
                        FontSize="9" 
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>

                </FlexLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the layout inside the definition of Grid. Now if you want dynamic content, you just need to bind the desired properties.
This is not correct because there's no definition for rows and etc, but you just need to define what you want dynamically on code behind and add rows and columns accordingly

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        //"Here you define your rows"
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        //"Here you define your columns"
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    //"Here you define your desired template"
    <FlexLayout                    
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                Direction="Column" AlignContent="Center"
                MinimumHeightRequest="110"
                WidthRequest="90"
                >
                <Button BorderColor="#fff"
                    BorderWidth="1"
                    BackgroundColor="#4D000000"
                    HeightRequest="90" CornerRadius="45"
                    Image="vera"/>

                <Label Text="Chat" 
                    Margin="0,4,0,0"
                    HeightRequest="20"
                    FontSize="9" 
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>

     </FlexLayout>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use Listview?

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemSource="{Binding ListOfItem}">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
<DateTemplate>
<ViewCell>
<FlexLayout   
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    Direction="Column" AlignContent="Center"
                    MinimumHeightRequest="110"
                    WidthRequest="90">
                    <Button BorderColor="#fff" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}"
                        BorderWidth="1"
                        BackgroundColor="#4D000000"
                        HeightRequest="90" CornerRadius="45"
                        Image="vera"/>

                    <Label Text="{Binding Text}" 
                        Margin="0,4,0,0"
                        HeightRequest="20"
                        FontSize="9" 
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
</FlexLayout>
<ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

As an ItemSource create a an object that contains Command property for your button and String for your Name, and create a list of those objects.